# Как сделать что бы при выборе select отображался только соответствующий inlines в админке?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

admin.py

```
class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = ('answer_text','points')
    readonly_fields = ('question',)
    extra = 0

class AnswerRadioInline(AnswerInline):
    model = AnswerRadio

class AnswerSelectMultipleInline(AnswerInline):
    model = AnswerSelectMultiple

class AnswerTextInline(AnswerInline):
    model= AnswerText

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [AnswerRadioInline,AnswerSelectMultipleInline,AnswerTextInline,]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочешь без перегрузки страницы, то можно подключить js, и прописать в нем, когда и какие прятать inline блоки , а какие отображать. Также понадобится css, где надо прописать, какие inline блоки не отображать изначально. У каждого inline блока есть свой уникальный id, которые ты можешь в своем браузер инспекторе пропалить.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ... твои конфиги
    class Media:
        css = (
            '/static/admin/css/mycss.css' # твои стили
        )
        js = (
            '/static/admin/js/myscript.js',   # твой скрипт
        )
```

Ну и если хочется по другому есть formtools:
https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#how-it-works